# Fast capture and 2D image stacking as 3D numpy array with Python and Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, image, numpy, raspberry-pi, python-imaging-library

I'm working on a Raspberry Pi project in which I need to take about 30 images per second (no movie) and stack each 2D image to a 3D array using numpy array, without saving each 2D capture as a file (because is slow).

I found this Python code to take images as fast as possible, but i don't know how to stack all images fast to a 3D stack of images.

```
import io
import time
import picamera
#from PIL import Image

def outputs():
    stream = io.BytesIO()
    for i in range(40):
        # This returns the stream for the camera to capture to
        yield stream
        # Once the capture is complete, the loop continues here
        # (read up on generator functions in Python to understand
        # the yield statement). Here you could do some processing
        # on the image...
        #stream.seek(0)
        #img = Image.open(stream)
        # Finally, reset the stream for the next capture
        stream.seek(0)
        stream.truncate()

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution = (640, 480)
    camera.framerate = 80
    time.sleep(2)
    start = time.time()
    camera.capture_sequence(outputs(), 'jpeg', use_video_port=True)
    finish = time.time()
    print('Captured 40 images at %.2ffps' % (40 / (finish - start)))
```

**Does anyone of you know how to stack the 2D images taken in this code to a 3D numpy array using Python and the Raspberry Pi camera module? Without saving each 2D capture as a file**

Best regards, Agustín

Comment: Are you wanting `numpy.dstack` http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html or are you looking for something more complex?

Comment: Hi Joe. Im want something like dstack, but i don't know how to implement it.

Comment: @AgustinCruz do you know beforehand how many images you will be stacking? If yes, you can pre-allocate your array and populate it after each image is captured.

Comment: Hi Saullo. Yes, the images quantity is fixed beforehand. I don't know how implement the preallocation in this code :(

Answer (score 0):

This might not work directly as copy-n-paste but should demonstrate how to pre-allocate memory and write results there. I'm not familiar with `pycamera` but the example [here](https://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/latest/recipes1.html) shows a bit different usage of in-memory streams.

```
import numpy as np

def outputs(resolution, n_pics, clr_channels=3):
    # Note that the first dimension is height and second is width
    images = np.zeros((resolution[1], resolution[0], clr_channels, n_pics), dtype=np.uint8)
    stream = io.BytesIO()

    for i in range(n_pics):
        yield stream
        images[:,:,:,i] = Image.open(stream)

        stream.seek(0)
        stream.truncate()
```